# Is anyone performed Function deployment in Azure Function in consumption based tier using zip deployment in Node?

Tags: node.js, azure, rest, azure-devops, azure-functions

Am able to achieve the same with Curl command:
curl -X POST -u user123:P@ssword --data-binary @"C:\Ddrive\Porject\deploy-zip\wb-uc1.zip" "https://abc-world.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy"
Need to deploy .zip file from local system to Azure function app.
I am very curious to perform this by using the NodeJS REST call. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I just tried webapp, will try function app for you.

Comment: @TonyJu - Let me know if u have any queries on above, You can try using curl as well just to verify.

Comment: The question is clear now. I will try both ways.

Comment: It also works fine, what is your file structure ?

Comment: @TonyJu- Appreciate your help. There was an issue in the file structure. Now it is working fine.

Comment: My pleasure and glad to hear that it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using curl post and REST call in nodejs both works fine. Here are my steps for your reference:

1.Created an comsumption nodejs function,created a http trigger function for test.

2.Went to the classic function app management experience ui and downloaded the app content

[image]

3.Unzipped tonytestzipdeploy.zip file and modified the http trigger function cotent, then zipped again. The file structure is

[image]

4.Ran the nodejs code to deploy the zip file.

```
var request=require('request')
var fs = require("fs")

var dataString=fs.createReadStream("D:\\testProject\\NodeJs\\HttpTrigger1.zip");

var options = {
    url: 'https://tonytestzipdeploy.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy',
    method: 'POST',
    body: dataString,
    auth: {
        'user': 'tonytestweb',
        'pass': 'XXX!'
    }
};

request.post(options, (error, response) => {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
})
```

5.Got the 200 status Code, and checked the function in azure portal, it was deployed successfully.

Reference:

[Zip deployment for Azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push)